# How to use private key in shellscript build configuration TeamCity

Tags: bash, build, teamcity

I want to create a build configuration in TeamCity composed of several steps. The build deploys files to a remote server.

In one of the steps, I run a shell script (bash) that receives some parameters. One of the parameters is a path to a private key. I need this path to be variable, since the key can be potentially changeable and I don't want to hard-code the path. I use the private key to make a SCP to the remote server in my script.

I've searched about this, but not found anything that meets my needs.

Please help me in achieving this or suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to define and use parameters in teamcity, you should go through [Configuring Build Parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Parameters). The idea is, teamcity allows you to define parameters and use them in build steps. Parameters values can be pre-defined and/or selected at the time of running the build.

Comment: Thank for answer. Indeed I already use custom parameters in my build steps. But one of this parameters must be the path to a private key in the teamcity server. Specifically I run a scripts that have a line like this:

Comment: `scp -i $1 directory-to-copy user@host:path`

I need pass the path to the private key in $1 parameter. Or somehow configure the build step to upload the directory to a remote server using a specific private key. Any suggestions are welcome.